# NEXTJS: try to show simple data json

Tags: html, json, next.js

I try to display the content of my JSON, the data is not updated, and it only displays my empty array(from dataContest). I tried to put as a return value of the function and other tests and looked at other forums, but nothing helped.

[the JSON comes from my supabase, this is the content I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW5vk.png)

my code :

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { supabase } from '../utils/supabaseClient'

export default function Auth() {
    const dataContest = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
      loadData()
    })

  async function loadData() {
      try {
        let { data: contest, error } = await supabase
          .from('contest')
          .select(`
            title, startDate, endDate, description,
            cryptoMonnaie (
              name
            ),
            category (
              name
            )
          `)
  
        if (error) {
          throw error
        }
        console.log(contest)
        dataContest.pop()
        dataContest.pop()
        dataContest.push(contest)
        
     
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message)
      } finally {
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className="row flex flex-center">
      <div className="col-8 form-widget">
        <h1 className="header">Contest Page</h1>
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Title</td>
              <td>StartDate</td>
              <td>EndDate</td>
              <td>Statut</td>
              <td>Category</td>
            </tr>
            {dataContest!=[] && dataContest.map((title, startDate, endDate, description, cryptoMonnaie, category) => (
                  <tr key={title}>
                    <td>{title}</td>
                    <td>{startDate}</td>
                    <td>{endDate}</td>
                    <td>{description}</td>
                    <td>{cryptoMonnaie}</td>
                    <td>{category}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

result :
[the result on the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT5S4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store your data using a state setter method. Re-iterating your code, you might have something like:

```
const YourComponent =  () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
      loadData()
    }, [])

    async function loadData() {
       const data = [/* your data fetched from the database */]
       
       setData(data)
    }

    return (/* your jsx */)
}
```

This is the correct way to use the useState hook. You might want to check this article out: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Do make sure to use JSON.parse(data_from_database) before putting it inside the stage.